# Volterra equation for a Bessel type IVP that appears in inverse scattering

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations, inverse-problems

I have the following i.v.p. (Colton Kress-Inverse acoustic and electromagnetic scattering theory, Springer)
$$y''(r)+(k^2n(r)-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2})y(r)=0$$
$$y(0)=0, y'(0)=1$$
using the Liouville transformation: $z(ξ)=y(r)n(r)^{1/4},\ ξ=\int_0^{r}n(t)dt$,
 the problem is transformed to
$$z''(ξ)+(k^2-\frac{l(l+1)}{ξ^2}-g(ξ))z(ξ)=0$$
$$z(0)=0,\ z'(0)=\frac{1}{n(0)^{1/4}}$$
for a suitable function g.

**I want to write the solution as a Volterra integral equation.**
In the case that l=0, it is easy to find that
$$z(ξ)=\frac{sin(kξ)}{kn(0)^{1/4}}+1/k\int_0^{ξ}sin(k(ξ-t))g(t)z(t)dt$$
If $l>0$, I would expect solutions in the form  $\sqrt{ξ} J_{l+1/2}(ξ)$ but I can't find the way.

Comment: what are the $J$?

Comment: @user66081 Presumably Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maple I am obtaining

$$z \left( \xi \right) =C\sqrt {\xi}{{\rm J_{L+1/2}}\left(\,\xi\,k\right)}
+1/2\,\sqrt {\xi}\pi \, \left( {{\rm J_{L+1/2}}\left(\,\xi\,k\right)}
\int _{0}^{\xi}\!\sqrt {\eta}{{\rm Y_{L+1/2,}}\left(\,\eta\,k\right)}g
 \left( \eta \right) z \left( \eta \right) {d\eta}-
{{\rm Y_{L+1/2,}}\left(\,\xi\,k\right)}\int _{0}^{\xi}\!\sqrt {\eta}
{{\rm J_{L+1/2,}}\left(\,\eta\,k\right)}g \left( \eta \right) z \left( 
\eta \right) {d\eta} \right) 
$$

Do you agree?

Comment: it looks fine,i expect something like that but i need the analytical method for the volterra equation. Something like the methods of Poschel Trubowitz-inverse spectral theory, if you are familiar..

Answer (score 0):

$y''(r)+\left(k^2n(r)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{r^2}\right)y(r)=0$

$\int_0^ry''(t)~dt+\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt=0$

$[y'(t)]_0^r+\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt=0$

$y'(r)-y'(0)+\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt=0$

$y'(r)+\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt-1=0$

$\int_0^ry'(t)~dt+\int_0^r\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt~dt=\int_0^rdt$

$[y(t)]_0^r+\int_0^r\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt~dt=[t]_0^r$

$y(r)-y(0)+\int_0^r\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt~dt=r$

$y(r)+\int_0^r\int_0^r\left(k^2n(t)-\dfrac{l(l+1)}{t^2}\right)y(t)~dt~dt=r$

Comment: this method is useful only in simple cases. In this case you can multiply the d.e for $z$ with a function $G(ξ,t)$ and integrate from $0-ξ$, then G satisfies $$G_{tt}(ξ,t)+(k^2+\frac{l(l+1)}{t^2})G(ξ,t)=0$$

Comment: $$G(ξ,ξ)=0,\ G_t(ξ,ξ)=-1$$. this method for $l=0$ gives the Volterra equation that i write above. For $l>0$ it should give an equation like Juan wrote above using Maple. The problem is that in this case $G(ξ,0)$ goes to infinty.